# Selecting elements from one column missing in another column, with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns, A and B, and I need to find every element on column B that is not on column A, and paste them in a third column, C.
For example:

```
A   B
23  5
1   4
5   7
4   23 
1
```

Then:

```
C
7
```

Searching for solutions, people usually suggest VLOOKUP() for similar problems. However, I need something with VBA, because each of these columns is in a different Workbook.
What is a good way to do this comparison?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest VLOOKUP (; VBA will be pretty slow if you use Loops on a big sample of data. Could you give us some more information about your data? Like: how big is your sample, do you need the columns in that exact order or is it possible to sort them, are there any other factors that have an impact on your data?

Comment: I just would like to inform you that you can accept answers by pressing the check sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops in Vba

```
counter = 0
k = 2

For i = 2 To lastrowA
    For j = 2 To lastRowB
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, "A") = Sheet1.Cells(j, "B") Then
            counter = 1
        End If
    Next j

    If counter = 0 Then
        Sheet1.Cells(k, "C") = Sheet1.Cells(j, "B")
        k = k + 1
    End If
    counter = 0
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/Ff194701.aspx) in VBA. Here is the syntax:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index, range_lookup)
```

Otherwise you could do loops

```
For each elementB in columnB
   For each elementA in columnA
      If elmentA <> ElementB then
         ---Save ElementA in an Array
      End if
   next elementB
next elementA
```